# Yahoo Email Autofill

Tags: yahoo-mail

When using yahoo's email service, I found that it will autofill emails of people not in my contacts list, and moreover people I've never even contacted. I know that I can remove these individually these emails, but I was wondering if there was an easier way to just restrict the autofill to my contacts, and what the cause of these spurious addresses might be.

Answer (score 1):

From looking around my own Yahoo mail account, I see that

1. The suggestions are coming from email that you have received in which the email addresses are mentioned in not only the from field, but also the CC field. So, if I send an email to you and to five other people as well via the CC field, the email addresses of those 5 other people will appear as suggestions when you are filling in the To field to compose an email address.
2. There seems to be no way to turn off this functionality.